# Assign a variable as key in an Array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an issue when I want to initialize an array. So basically I'm using the library ngx-gauge to display gauges in my application and one of the attributes is thresholds to have three different colors depending of the value. for example:
`thresholds = {'0' : {color:'red'}, '100' : {color:'green'}, '200': {color:'orange'}};`

My problem is that I want to put instead of '0','100' and '200' a variable. What I tried to do is:

```
const level1 = manager.getLevelOne();
const level2 = manager.getLevelTwo();
const level3 = manager.getLevelThree();
thresholds ={ level1 : {color:'red'}, level2:{color:'green'}, level3:{color:'orange'}};
```

However when I console.log thresholds it shows level1,2 and 3 as alias and not their value.

Comment: Use `thresholds = {}; thresholds[level1] = {color:'red'}; thresholds[level2] = {color:'green'};` and so on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why `thresholds= { level1: {color: 'red'}}` does not work is because it is equivalent to `thresholds= { "level1": color: 'red'}}` (with quotes). The two versions are equivalent in JavaScript as long as `level1` is a legal identifier, and the second version makes it clear what's going on.

```js
const level1 = "0";
const level2 = "100";
const level3 = "200";
thresholds = {
  [level1]: {
    color: 'red'
  },
  [level2]: {
    color: 'green'
  },
  [level3]: {
    color: 'orange'
  }
};
console.log(thresholds);
```